# Symfony 5 mailer : Failed to authenticate on SMTP

Tags: symfony, sendgrid, api-key, mailer

I'm trying to use the new Mailer on Symfony 5.2 by following this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html).
I did a MailingController like this:

```
/**
 * @var EntityManagerInterface
 */
private $entityManager;

/**
 * @var Swift_Mailer
 */
private $mailer;

/**
 * MailingController constructor.
 *
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
 * @param Swift_Mailer $mailer
 */
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
                            Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}


/**
 * @Route("/email")
 * @param MailerInterface $mailer
 * @return Response
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface
 */
public function sendEmail(MailerInterface $mailer): Response
{
    $email = (new Email())
        ->from('hello@example.com')
        ->to('hello@example.com')
        //->cc('cc@example.com')
        //->bcc('bcc@example.com')
        //->replyTo('fabien@example.com')
        //->priority(Email::PRIORITY_HIGH)
        ->subject('Time for Symfony Mailer!')
        ->text('Sending emails is fun again!')
        ->html('<p>See Twig integration for better HTML integration!</p>');

    $mailer->send($email);

    // ...
}
```

And for my config I did this in .env.local:

```
###> symfony/sendgrid-mailer ###
SENDGRID_KEY=KEY
MAILER_DSN=sendgrid+smtp://$SENDGRID_KEY@default
###< symfony/sendgrid-mailer ###
```

Then I get this error:

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "apikey" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN", "PLAIN". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException: Expected response code "235" but got code "451", with message "451 Authentication failed
```

I'm stuck with this error, I've looked everywhere on the net but can't find anything to get rid of this error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as you can see i don't use the swiftMailer dependency, I use the MailerInterface in the function sendEmail.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the problem, I changed the config in the .env.local to this:

```
###> symfony/sendgrid-mailer ###
SENDGRID_KEY=KEY
MAILER_DSN=sendgrid+smtp://$SENDGRID_KEY@default
###< symfony/sendgrid-mailer ###
```

It's working great now.

Comment: That's the same code than in the question. What was changed?